# How to after django form is submitted to be redirected to another webpage and have form data to be sent to backend database

Tags: javascript, python, django

Aim: for when django form is submitted for data to be sent and saved to admin side.

problem: i can redirect it to another page after form is submitted but when i go onto admin side the data is not saved. how can i fix this? using django or javascript?

html:

```
    <form method="post"  >
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{form.as_p}}
                        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Log In">
                    </form>
```

models.py:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django import forms
    
    
    
    class Customer(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='')
        last_name = models.CharField(
            max_length=200, verbose_name='')
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.first_name + ', ' + self.last_name
```

forms.py:

```
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from django import forms
    from .models import Customer
    
    
    class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Customer
            fields = '__all__'
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import CustomerForm


def index(request):

    form = CustomerForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
```

Ash this is what it gives me: [image: the code and error it gives me]
if you need any other files just ask

the redirect error i get
[image: the error it gives me]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing form.save() you can say:

return redirect(link to redirect to)

This will redirect you to the chosen place after the form is validated and saved.

Comment: i added to the post a picture of the code and error it returns when i do that

Comment: try typing this exactly ,     return redirect ('https://www.google.com/')

Comment: it tells me when i tried it that redirect isnt defined

Comment: Make sure to type from django.shortcuts import redirect at the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

Add one line after your form will save

```
# put link inside -> " "
return redirect("Link")
```

Comment: thanks but i did that and i got an error i added an image of what im getting on the post

Comment: it gives me an error saying name 'redirect' is not defined

Comment: import this package -> from django.shortcuts import redirect

Answer (score 0):

Change the html as method="POST"

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('urlname')
else:
    form = CustomerForm()
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
```